# Is it possible to use the search results of one search as the criteria for a new search in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Using NetSuite is it possible to embed a search within another search?  I have a search that I need that will be effectively using another search's results in the criteria.

The basic structure of my search is:

```
Return all non-inventory skus, starting with a specific prefix,
    Where the occurrence of the previously mentioned skus on a custom field on
    Inventory-Part records is greater than 0.
```

This is then intended to be used for alerts

I'm not sure how to build this within NetSuite's search builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this pertains to any scripting as m_cheung suggested.

To answer your question, yes this is doable via saved search.

1. Transaction > Management > Saved Search > New
2. Select 'Item' from the list
3. In the criteria section:

   - Type = 'Non-Inventory Items'
   - External ID = starts with (...your desired prefix) (NOTE: Assuming that prefix is the external ID from your question)
   - Select the Custom field and criteria is greater than 0.
   - Save and Run to confirm if this is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

using nlapiSearchRecord(**RECORDTYPE**, **JOIN_, __SEARCHFILTERSARRAY, __SEARCHCOLUMNSARRAY**) you can return the results of a search and pass the returned data further into script logic

for example if you build search1 using a searchFilter array and a searchColumn array then pass these arrays into nlapiSearchRecord('item'), you can assign this call to a variable:

var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, searchFiltersArray, searchColumnsArray);

then using searchresults (which is an nlobjSearchResults object) you can pull out your returned search data for criteria in search2:

```
if(searchresults)
{
  for(i=0;i<searchresults.length; i++)
  {
    var search2FilterAndColumnData = searchresults[i].getAllColumns();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a saved search for creating another search in suitescript.
Somewhat like ,

**var arrSearchResult = nlapiSearchRecord( null , SAVED_SEARCH_ID , FILTERS , COLUMNS);**